NGINX Plus OpenId Configurations
We are evaluating NGINX Plus as a proxy server in conjunction with WSO2 Identity Server 7. Our focus is on enabling authentication for a protected resource using OAuth2. We have completed the necessary configuration for both NGINX and WSO2, and are actively working on integrating these systems.
we are able to get Oauth code after the configurations but while trying to get Oauth token using the Oauth code we are facing below mentioned error on ngnix plus
*2024/08/11 13:41:01 [error] 51555#51555: *14 api.asgardeo.io could not be resolved (110: Operation timed out), client: 10.1.1.1, server: , request: "GET /_codexch?code=95efd978-94e9-3bfb-a006-449fbebf5a13&session_state=45532ec0ad53d52e9d0978d062444547e3fdbbf485f9abdeda571faa8961b2c6.iY6RQZ6vjEPIBPvLO4O2-A&state=0 HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/_token", host: "test.is.com", referrer: "http://abc.is.com/" 2024/08/11 13:41:01 [error] 51555#51555: 14 js: OIDC unexpected response from IdP when sending authorization code (HTTP 502).

Please note that we are able to call the token API with the same authentication code from the postman and receive the access token.

Many Thanks
